# React Native: do you have to do manual linking for AsyncStorage?

Tags: react-native, npm, cocoapods, asyncstorage, podfile

I'm following [this guide](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/) for adding AsyncStorage to my React Native app. I'm using react native v0.63.4, but I'm using a Mac, so I'm wondering whether the manual linking that they cite for MacOS at the bottom is something I have to do. For instance, in the manual linking guidelines it says to add a line for AsyncStorage in your podfile, and when I just did `npm i...` and `pod install`, there was no line added to my podfile. Do I have to do this manual linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do the manual linking. Since the 0.60 version of React Native, it was released a feature called [autolinking](https://medium.com/@srbkrishnan/react-native-auto-linking-on-android-65a850bb9ed9). That is, when you execute the `npm install` or `yarn add` the lib is linked already, the pod install is just to install dependencies behind the scenes, it does not have to be necessarily in the podfile.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what the MacOS section is about then? Does React Native build apps for desktop now or something?

Comment: Yes, with React Native you can make apps for [window and macos too](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/).